# URL Rewrite Module, Azure and web.config

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, azure

I'm trying to use the URL rewrite module in Azure but for some reason I can't add  a `<rewrite>` section to the web.config's system.webServer section (as shown on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573358.aspx).

I've installed the URL Rewrite Modeul v2via the Web Platform Installer. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with the v4.0 framework and a standard ASP.NET Work Role.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "can't add a <rewrite> section..." What happens when you try?

Comment: The web.config parser doesn't recognize the element so I can't compile the code

Comment: It sounds like your install of the URL Rewrite module didn't work, then.

Comment: The install reported "Successful"

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling it. If you already fixed the issue, please post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying to Microsoft Azure platform, there is no need to install any rewrite module. Is already installed on the IIS7.

If your visual studio doesn't allow to publish or generate the package, you can try to install the module on your dev machine.

I reproduced your error on a Visual Studio 2010 express, having the same warning and I'm able to generate the package, then, if you are working in another version, you could try to upgrade. No rewrite module installed on my pc.